# Change .asp file style (css)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, axd

I have .aspx file (i dont have the .aspx file code), I'm trying to change the direction of .html page via .css file.
My problem is that the .css file is dynamic loaded from .axd file.
How can i change .css file at this case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript. like

```
document.getElementById('id').style.property = 'value';
document.getElementById('id').setAttribute("dir", "value");
```

Comment: yeah..but i have a big .html file.. i want to be able to change at .css file the direction and all the elements using at this class

Comment: big html file won't stop you from using javascript. And you cant set attributes using CSS, you have to use javascript for that( assuming you are referencing to the dir attribute of html tag)

Comment: when i need to do that? on page ready/load? this is the best way to do that?

Comment: i can to do that maybe to the <html> tag to all page instaed of any element?

Comment: yes you can do that at onloadstart/onload/document.ready etc, doesn't make much difference